# How do i GET the HTML of another URL after it loads all scripts and the last item is loaded in jquery or php

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying Web Scrape a page but , there are some elements that i need that are only loaded after some seconds when all the scripts loads. When i try to get() with jquery ajax it returns me the html before it is loaded.

OBS : With selenium js i can get the complete HTML but i need something to work only with jquery :

```
const {Builder,By,Key,util} = require("selenium-webdriver");
let driver =  new Builder().forBrowser("chrome").build(); // intialize chrome
driver.get(url);
await driver.sleep(10000) // Waits till the page is loaded
var html= await driver.executeScript("return  
document.documentElement.outerHTML") // returns complete html
```

How can i get the complete HTML with only jquery?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you be more specific? It depends on what this `driver` object supports. Since I'm not sure what `driver` is, I cannot delve deeper into finding a solution. A good question can be reproducible by anyone. [Tips for making a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Edited, the code is just to show that i can get the html with Selenium js , but i would like to only need jquery for this

Comment: In theory you could goto the page that you want, open your browser's network console and determine which remote call is pulling in the data. Then `try` to work directly with that URL.

Comment: @imvain2 the url that it is calling , is a API that i dont have acess to